# Javascript created button wont display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I have created a countdown timer(almost) using HTML and Javascript. I use Javascript to create a text input and a button (to start timer).

However when I run the page the output is just two text text input boxes and I cant for the life of me figure it out. I have tried the page in different browsers with the same result. As a test I also tried to make the button the first element and it still displays as a text input.

I used a debugger and when it shows the HTML (as created by javascript) it shows two  items without any closing  tags. I am not sure if thats how the debugger displays created elements or if the closing tags are actually missing when I create the input element using Javascript.

I have attached: my HTML page, Javascript code snippet related to creating elements, and the related snippet of the HTML output as shown in the debugger.

I appreciate any help as I am at a loss.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript - CountDown</title>
    <style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
  }

  #container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="inputArea">
</div>

<h1 id="time">0:00 </h1>
 </div>

 <script src="script.js"> </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Javascript:

```
// as soon as page is loaded
window.onload = function () {
//create input text box and give it a name of 'minutes'
var inputMinutes = document.createElement("input");
inputMinutes.setAttribute = ("id", "minutes");
inputMinutes.setAttribute = ("type", "text");

//create a button
var startButton = document.createElement("input");
startButton.setAttribute = ("type", "button");
startButton.setAttribute = ("value", "Start Countdown");

startButton.onclick = function () {
    startCountdown();
};

// add to the DOM to div called inputArea
document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(inputMinutes);
document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(startButton);
};
```

HTML Output as per the debugger:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="inputArea">
<input>
<input>
</div>
<h1 id="time">0:00 </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.setAttribute is a function with the syntax
`element.setAttribute(name, value)`

So your code should be

```
//create input text box and give it a name of 'minutes'
var inputMinutes = document.createElement("input");
inputMinutes.setAttribute("id", "minutes");
inputMinutes.setAttribute("type", "text");

//create a button
var startButton = document.createElement("input");
startButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
startButton.setAttribute("value", "Start Countdown");
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SptAu/)

Comment: Perfect and Thank You it is now working as I expected. I am new to programming and syntax is killing me when debugger can't catch. That is why I practice. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OP was writing it code as inputMinutes.setAttribute = ("id", "minutes")' I changed it to inputMinutes.setAttribute("id", "minutes")

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a button like this in your javascript code

```
//create a button
var startButton = document.createElement("button");
startButton.innerHTML ="Start Countdown";
```

see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Miciurash/J5JmJ/

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will keep this in mind. I am new to coding and always open to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

MarsOne's answer is correct, you just had the `setAttribute` syntax wrong. Incidentally, all the attributes you are setting are also native properties of the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), so you can do them like this:

```
inputMinutes.id = "minutes";
inputMinutes.type = "text";
```

. . .

```
startButton.type = "submit";
startButton.value = "Start Countdown";
```

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate the help and alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating input as element, we can create button using JavaScript:

```
var startButton = document.createElement("button");
startButton.innerHTML ="Start Countdown";

document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(startButton);
```

else

```
 var startButton = document.createElement("input");
 startButton.type="button"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Shoaib, I appreciate your input.